# Javascript, json

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Подаю на сервер AJAX GET запрос, получаю ответ в json: `[{"type": "button", "name": "\u0420\u00ad\u0420\u0454\u0421\u0403\u0421\u201a\u0421\u0402\u0420\u00b5\u0420\u0405\u0420\u0405\u0420\u00b0\u0421\u040f \u0420\u0455\u0421\u0403\u0421\u201a\u0420\u00b0\u0420\u0405\u0420\u0455\u0420\u0406\u0420\u0454\u0420\u00b0"}]` Где \uXXXX должен быть русский текст. Далее JSON.parse и там этот текст превращается в `Р­РєСЃС‚СЂРµРЅРЅР°СЏ РѕСЃС‚Р°РЅРѕРІРєР°`. Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так.

Comment: Не знаю где вы это сделали, но это UTF-8 прочётнный как windows1251 и закодированный в `\uXXXX`. Чините сервер

Comment: Сервер присылает некорректные данные, нужно чинить именно сервер.

Comment: Спасибо, вы правы. Проблема была на сервере